# boost asio, post() to main thread?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio` as a general async backend.

I have multiple threads runing one `io_context`

But I encounter certain operations that are binded to specific thread. For example, `imshow` of opencv must be called from main thread.

What is the best way to post to main thread, or any specific thread in general? (without busy loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it through asio.
You can use message queue you read in main thread (like Windows messages) or other specific thread.

Comment: Or you can use multiple io_context's. And one of them is being run in main thread.

Comment: Thanks. Is there elegant way to run two io_context without busy looping?

Comment: @somebody4: The way you would normally do that would be have all of the thread calling io_context::run(), which will generally block.  You will neeed to use executor_work_guard to ensure that there is always 'work' on the io_context, so run doesn't return prematurely.  In your case, with two contexts, the threads could post to the 'helper' context or the 'main' context.  The threads would block until there are function objects to run.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make `main` participate in a thread_pool (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/thread_pool/attach.html)